# How to set the custom Microsoft visual studio projects MSI to open it without admin power

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I want to know if there some options to set the MSI file without admin power. When I open the msi file in non-admin user, it always need admin power. How can I set it to open the msi file without the admin power? Based on my search, I find the remote desktop has the behavior, but I could not find the settings in Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects.

I want to use MSI installer for non-admin user.